# How do I reload a model in Entity Framework 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching, entity-framework-core

I've read that in previous versions of the entity framework, you had access to a `Reload()` method, like this: `Db.Entry<DatabaseModels.User>(_me).Reload();`

I get an error from that saying that EntityEntry does not contain a definition for 'Reload'.

The reason why I even want to reload is from caching (or what I think is caching, and EF possibly not knowing when to invalidate the cache).

Example:

Load userA.
Create item that userA will own.
Try to access that new item through the relationship on the user.
userA.Items returns empty
re-fetch userA from the database, and call the relationship, and the newly created item is in the association.

Not sure why that's happening, or if there is a way to get EF to be smarted about cache invalidation.

Comment: Can't you just add the item to userA straight away? `Item myItem = new Item(...); userA.Items.Add(myItem); context.SaveChanges();` Also are you sure you didn't disable proxy creation?

Comment: how would I know if I've disabled proxy creation?

Comment: `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` must be true

Comment: EF7 doesn't appear to have a configuration property on the context

Comment: Well if you didn't touch it it's good, it's enabled by default anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't supported, but you can do it through code, by inspecting the metadata. See here an example: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/implementing-missing-features-in-entity-framework-core.